# Preference: Convexity and Monotonicity

Tags: microeconomics, preferences, self-study

I need an example of a

- Convex, non-monotonic preference
- Non-convex, monotonic preference

I figured that an example of non-convex, monotonic utility preference could be $U(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.
For convex, non-monotonic preference, I cannot think of a standard example. As far as my understanding goes, lexicographic preferences are convex, but I don't think these are non monotonic. 
Please help me figure out the examples so that I can conceptually understand monotonicity and convexity.

Comment: $-(x-1)^2 -(y-1)^2$ is an example of convex, non- monotonic preference

Comment: @Amit Thank You!

Comment: @Amit Also post answers you think are correct as answers.

Comment: It's an example of an utility function that represents convex, non-monotonic preferences, actually.

Answer (score 4):

$u_1(x, y) = -(x-1)^2 - (y-1)^2$

$u_2(x, y) = -|x-1| - |y-1|$

are examples of utility functions that are concave, and therefore represent the preferences that are convex. Also, these preferences are not monotonic.